# How to treat $\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin(kx)dx =\frac {1}{k}$ as a distribution?

Tags: improper-integrals, distribution-theory, weak-convergence

How to evaluate the following integral?

$\int_{0}^{\infty}  \sin(kx)dx=\frac 1 k$

The book Mathematical Physics by Butkov reads "The sequence $f_N(k)=\int_{0}^{N} \sin(kx) dx=\frac{(1-\cos kN)}k$diverges as N approaches $\infty$, but it is weakly convergent for a suitable chosen set of test functions $g(k)$ defined $0<k<\infty$."
The problem is how to choose the test function?

Comment: Is the lower limit of the integral zero or minus infinity?

Comment: The lower limit is 0.

Comment: I think there must be limit of the integral as $k\rightarrow\infty$ and so the result must be zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $\varphi \in C_c^\infty ((0,\infty))$ and call $f_n(k) = \int_0^n \sin(ky) dy = \frac{1-\cos(nk)}{k}$.  We would like to show that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^\infty \varphi(k) f_n(k) dk = \int_{0}^\infty \varphi(k) \frac{1}{k} dk
\end{align*}
which would show that as distributions on $C_c^\infty ((0,\infty))$, $f_n(k) \to \frac{1}{k}$. It suffices to show that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^\infty \frac{\varphi(k)}{k}\cos(nk)dk = 0
\end{align*}
Notice that since $\varphi$ is a smooth function compactly supported away from $0$, $\frac{\varphi(k)}{k}$ is a continuous function of compact support on $\mathbb{R}$ and is therefore an $L^1$ function.  The result now follows from the [Riemann Lebesgue Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma).

Answer (score 0):

We should calculate the limit: $\displaystyle\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int_{0}^\infty\sin(kx)\phi(x)dx$ for every $\phi\in C_0^\infty(0, \infty)$, i.e, $\phi$ is a test function. Integration by parts implies that $$\displaystyle\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int_{0}^\infty\sin(kx)\phi(x)dx$$
$$=-\displaystyle\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int_{0}^\infty\frac{\cos(kx)}{k}\phi'(x)dx$$
and since $$\bigg|\int_{0}^\infty\frac{\cos(kx)}{k}\phi'(x)dx\bigg|\leq\frac{1}{k}\int_0^\infty\cos(kx)\phi'(x)dx\leq\frac{1}{k}\int_0^\infty|\phi'(x)|dx,$$
where the latter integral is finite (this is because $\phi(x)$ has a compact support in $(0, \infty)$), the result of the integral is zero as $k\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: This is Riemann Lebesgue, which is a different question.  Also, your last inequality cannot be right.  The right hand side can easily be negative, while the left is positive.  You need absolute values inside the integral.  You probably also want to estimate that $|\cos(kx)|$ by $1$.

Comment: shouldn't we consider the behavior of    $\int_{0}^{\infty}(\int_{0}^{N}sin(kx)dx)\phi(k)dk$   instead of $\int_{0}^{\infty}sin(kx)\phi(x)dx$,where $\phi(k)$is a test function? I mean we should treat $f(k)=\int_{0}^{\infty}sin(kx)dx$     as a distribution(generized function). I don't have a systematic knowledge of distribution, so it might be wrong.@user103567

Comment: You are right @ChrisJanjigian thanks I will edit it